# Spring boot external config in a docker environment: application.yml does not exist

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, kubernetes, jib

Before start explaining my issue, it's worth mentioning that although I am trying to work how to use Maven Jib plugin in conjunction with Spring Boot and Kubernetes, the issue is the same even if I try to use a normal docker.

I have used Kubernetes configMap to create the application.yml file and mount it as an external file to the Pod (`/config/application.yml`). The issue I have been facing is my application does not able to find the `application.yml` file and throw a typical exception:

```
ERROR [main] org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication: Application run failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to parse configuration class [com.example.Application]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [application.yml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
```

I have tried different approaches with Jib by using different arguments such as below.

```
  <container>
    <extraClasspath>/config/*</extraClasspath>
    <args>
      <arg>--spring.config.location=file:/config/application.yml</arg>
    </args>
    <jvmFlags>
      <jvmFlag>-Dspring.config.location=classpath:/,classpath:/config/,file:./,file:./config/,file:/config/</jvmFlag>
    </jvmFlags>
  </container>
```

None of them has worked for me. I have also tried to use the `SPRING_CONFIG_NAME` environment variable and set it to `file:/config/application.yml` for the pod, but still the same issue.

I can verify that the config file exists in the specified location and there are no permission issues (as far as I can tell).

Interestingly, when I create just an empty `application.yml` file in the default classpath `(src/main/resources)` then it passes the first verification and the application loads successfully (with using the actual values from `/config/application`), so whatever the issue is it is being impacted by an initial verification of Spring Boot before even passing the application file to the corresponding classes.

Comment: share your kubernetes deployment YAMLs

Comment: When you specify `--spring.config.location=file:/config/application.yml` that and only that configuration file will be loaded, nothing else. If it cannot be found, well the applicaiton crashes. Try with `--spring.config.additional-location=file:/config/` it will now add that to the list of valid locations to detect a configuration file.

Comment: Please share your `application.yml` in order to debug the environment and help others with the same issue.

Comment: I have actually found what the issue is. It's just related to 'extraClasspath'. I only needed to use that with '/config/' only without *. Thanks all for you help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the only item I need to have is the following:

```
<container>
    <extraClasspath>/config</extraClasspath> <!-- No need to have * at the end -->
</container>
```